# Seting up kinect and sample apps in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, kinect

I am trying to setup kinect on my windows 8 system.Is there any easy tutorial or sample applications to test simple gestures and all with kinect

Comment: You can start off with the following link, it is really useful:  http://www.packtpub.com/article/getting-started-with-kinect-for-windows-sdk-programming

Comment: Try the [j4k examples](http://research.dwi.ufl.edu/ufdw/j4k/examples.php)